# Python Selenium Element click

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

With my beginner knowledge in selenium I have tried to find the click element, to the open the link. There is not href for link for these items. How can I perform click on correct element to open the link.

I am using python, selenium, chrome web driver, BeautifulSoup. All libraries are updated.

Below is the sample html snippet where there is a title I need to click on using selenium. Please let me know if you need more html source. This code is from a "sign in" only website.

```
<h2> <!--For Verified item-->
  <a class="clickable" style="cursor:pointer;" onmousedown="open_item_detail('0000013', '0', false)" id="View item Detail" serial="0000013">
    Sample Item
  </a>
  <!--For unverified item-->
</h2>
```

Comment: share the link and the name of the item you want to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Sample Item"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2 a.clickable[onmousedown^='open_item_detail']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2//a[@class='clickable' and starts-with(@onmousedown, 'open_item_detail')][contains(., 'Sample Item')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: How to loop through these sort of links to click and come back. When I try to loop click it only click first link only.

Comment: @ACE Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please? Would be glad to help you out.

Comment: This new question has been asked several times on SO. A search should help you find them.

Answer (score 2):

wait for the element, then find by the right xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://yourpage.com")
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//contains(a[text(),"Sample Item")]')))
elem.click()
```